# Repository save has no effect in rest-controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am encountering a weird issue in one of our rest-controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/export")
@RestController
public class ExportRestController {

// ...

@Autowired
HereService hereService;

@Autowired
BookingLegRepository bookingLegRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/csv/{year}/{month}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PRIV_CAN_EXPORT_BOOKINGS')")
public void getCsvExport(
  @PathVariable("year") Integer year,
  @PathVariable("month") Integer month,
  Authentication auth,
  HttpServletResponse response) throws EntityNotFoundException {

   // ...

   // fetch data from db
   final var bookingLegs = bookingLegRepository.findByStartTimewindowStartBetweenAndDistributorId(from, to, distributor.getId())
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(BookingLegEntity::getCreationTimestamp))
            .toList();

   final HashSet<BookingLegEntity> blsToUpdate = new HashSet<>();
  for (BookingLegEntity bl : bookingLegs) {
     if (bl.getFrom().getZipcode() == null || bl.getFrom().getCounty() == null) {
        bl.setFrom(hereService.tryEnrichLocationWithZipCodeAndCounty(bl.getFrom()));
        blsToUpdate.add(bl);
     }
  }
  bookingLegRepository.saveAll(blsToUpdate); // bulk update for performance
  // ...
}

// ...
}
```

I am calling `bookingLegRepository.saveAll(blsToUpdate)` here to store the new updated booking-legs that have been enriched with location-data here: `bl.setFrom(hereService.tryEnrichLocationWithZipCodeAndCounty(bl.getFrom()))`.

If I debug the code, I can see that the booking-legs in the repository are updated correctly. But it does not work in production.

It also does not work in my integration test:

```
package de.mopla.server.integration;

import de.mopla.server.core.repositories.BookingLegRepository;
import de.mopla.server.core.repositories.DistributorRepository;
import de.mopla.server.core.services.ExportService;
import de.mopla.server.core.services.here.HereService;
import de.mopla.server.core.services.here.model.Address;
import de.mopla.server.core.services.here.model.Item;
import de.mopla.server.core.services.here.model.RevGeocodeResult;
import de.mopla.server.schedule.integration.AbstractSchedulingIntegrationTest;
import io.zonky.test.db.AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.flywaydb.test.annotation.FlywayTest;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "scheduler.key.minutesOfTimeShift=10",
    "scheduler.cron.runAll=-",
})
//@Ignore // todo MC-1942 find out why this does not work on the server
public class ExportServiceIntegrationTest extends AbstractSchedulingIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ExportServiceTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean("fakeHereService")
        @Primary
        public HereService hereService() {
            final HereService mock = mock(HereService.class);
            final var mockedResult = new RevGeocodeResult();
            final var item = new Item();
            final var address = new Address();
            address.setPostalCode("111111");
            address.setCounty("Bavaria");
            item.setAddress(address);
            mockedResult.setItems(List.of(item));
            when(mock.reverseGeocode(anyDouble(), anyDouble())).thenReturn(mockedResult);
            when(mock.tryEnrichLocationWithZipCodeAndCounty(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
            return mock;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private BookingLegRepository bookingLegRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ExportService exportService;

    @Autowired
    private DistributorRepository distributorRepository;

    @Test
//    @Transactional (integration test works if I add this - does not work in production though)
    @Sql("/fixtures/booking_leg_2.sql")
    @FlywayTest
    public void exportServiceAddsZipCodeAndCounty() throws Exception {
        final var before = bookingLegRepository.findAll();

        final var token = mockIamTheDistributor(distributorRepository);

        // fix timestamps
        before.forEach(bl -> {
            bl.setCreationTimestamp(java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
            bookingLegRepository.save(bl);
        });

        assertTrue(before.stream().allMatch(bl -> bl.getFrom().getZipcode() == null));
        assertTrue(before.stream().allMatch(bl -> bl.getFrom().getCounty() == null));

        useApiToGetCsvExport(token, 2022, 11);

        final var after = bookingLegRepository.findAll();

        // TODO these fail:
        assertTrue(after.stream().allMatch(bl -> bl.getFrom().getZipcode() != null));
        assertTrue(after.stream().allMatch(bl -> bl.getFrom().getCounty() != null));

    }

}
```

Here is the definition of the `BookingLegRepository`:

```
@SentrySpan
@Repository
public interface BookingLegRepository extends JpaRepository<BookingLegEntity, UUID>, CustomBookingLegRepository {
   
   // ...

   // find all booking-legs for given distributor and given date
    @Query("select b from BookingLegEntity b left join fetch b.belongsTo where b.startTimewindowStart between ?1 and ?2 and b.distributor.id = ?3")
    List<BookingLegEntity> findByStartTimewindowStartBetweenAndDistributorId(Instant from, Instant to, UUID distributorId);

}
```

If I add a `@Transactional` in the test method, it works, but in production it still fails. So I am pretty sure it has something to do with the transaction not being commited, but cannot figure out why that is. Can this be related to the fact, that I try to update a database inside a GET-controller?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code of BookingLegRepository. At least the first part of it.

Comment: Sure, I added it to my question (also the part where I query the booking-legs).

Comment: Do you have EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your application main class? Or alternatively spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in pom.xml?

Comment: Other quick check. On the startup log you should see: "Finished Spring Data repository scanning... Found N JPA repository interfaces. If N is zero then you have a configuration issue.

Comment: I can see that there is no update being commited in the logs

Comment: What about the quick check above? Can you see "Found N JPA repository interfaces" in the startup log? This is essential because if not properly auto-configured, JPA repositories don't use any transactions at all.

Comment: Yes, sure. I see: `Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 574 ms. Found 24 JPA repository interfaces.` in the startup log of the integration test.

Comment: In this case the JPARepository method saveAll() will run with Transactional annotation. If it doesn't work there must be something in your code that changes this flow. What about @SentrySpan? Can you just for test remove this annotation?